# Extending ajax content to go next or prev

Tags: jquery, popup, magnific-popup

Is it possible to extend the Magnific popup to go next or previous within the open popup window without closing the box and reopening a new one with new ajax content in it?

I love what http://www.julianabicycles.com/ did.  When you scroll down and click on a bicycle, it opens ajax content, then they have navigation in it that allows you to skip to the next ajax content. If it is not possible to do this with Magnific, are there alternative ajax jQuery plugins that would enable me to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking to do the same thing but haven't found a solution yet. The example provided in the docs (http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/sHoxp) almost works, but there's no way (that I know of) to tell MagnificPopup to start the modal with a specific piece of content from the json source.